# Rename files from a list but remove used lines?

Tags: batch-file

I found this from another thread. All it does is it renames files with names from a list. However, this doesn't automatically remove used names. Is it possible to make it do that?

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

rem Load the list of new filenames
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (names.txt) do (
   set /A i+=1
   set "newname[!i!]=%%a"
)
rem Do the rename:
set i=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /o:n *.doc') do (
   set /A i+=1
   for %%i in (!i!) do ren "%%a" "!newname[%%i]!"
)
```

Comment: remove used lines??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an enhanced batch file which removes all file names from `names.txt` used on renaming files.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "NamesListFile=names.txt"

rem Does the file with the list of new file names not exist?
if not exist "%NamesListFile%" goto EndBatch

rem Delete in local environment all environment variables
rem of which name starts with the string "newname[".
for /F "delims==" %%I in ('set newname[ 2^>nul') do set "%%I="

rem Load the list of new file names and assign them to environment variables.
set "NameIndex=0"
for /F "usebackq eol=| delims=" %%I in ("%NamesListFile%") do (
    set /A NameIndex+=1
    set "newname[!NameIndex!]=%%I"
)

rem Do the file renames as long as there is a new file name available in list.
set "NamesCount=%NameIndex%"
set "NameIndex=0"
set "RenameCount=0"
for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /B /O:N *.doc 2^>nul') do (
    set /A NameIndex+=1
    for %%J in (!NameIndex!) do (
        if defined newname[%%J] (
            ren "%%I" "!newname[%%J]!"
            set /A RenameCount+=1
        ) else goto RebuildList
    )
)

:RebuildList
rem Was no file found to rename?
if %RenameCount% == 0 goto EndBatch
rem Were all new names used to rename files?
if %RenameCount% == %NamesCount% (
    del "%NamesListFile%"
    goto EndBatch
)
rem Create a new file names list with used file names removed.
set /A RenameCount+=1
(for /L %%I in (%RenameCount%,1,%NamesCount%) do echo !newname[%%I]!)>"%NamesListFile%"

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

Limitations of this batch file:

1. It does not work for file names containing one or more `!`.
2. It does not verify if every file rename was successful at all.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `ren /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`